# Generating a word document using React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, docx

I have a React app and I want to generate a word document using a partially template using the information a user fills in the input form. So for example:

There is a template word document:

My name is `{firstname}` and i live at `{address}`.

The form is something like

```
<View>
  <TextInput
    value={this.state.firstname}
    placeholder={'firstname'}
  />
  <TextInput
    value={this.state.address}
    placeholder={'Address'}
  />
</View>
```

I understand redocx can be used to generate something like this but can redocx be used on template/partially documents that already have words on them and require only user inputs in the app to be completed and then generated. Is there a way this can be achieved using react native.